# Значение функции плотности вероятности единица

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

Как интерпретировать плотность распределения f(x), для которой на нескольких событиях, она принимает значение 1? В таком случае оказывается, что несколько событий одновременно должны оказаться свершившимися.

Пример.

f(0.5) = 1

f(0.6) = 1

Как возможно, что одновременно существует и 0.5 и 0.6 c вероятностью 1?

Comment: У нас тут сайт не по математике, а по программированию. (Вы ж не новичок, должны знать уже.)

Comment: @VladD Ах, какая оговорка! - по Фрейду?

Comment: @Igor: Она самая :)

Comment: @VladD почему-то у некоторых чем больше репа, тем больше уверенность, что можно постить разный трэш.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: По себе знаю! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Плотность вероятности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) в точке `x` это некоторая мера того, как часто будет встречаться значения, примерно равные `x`, но никак не вероятность получить именно значение `x`. Более того, имеет смысл лишь значение плотности на некотором отрезке `[x, y]`, так как можно изменить плотность любого распределения в конечном числе точек на любую величину и распределение не изменится.

Например, рассмотрим равномерное распределение на отрезке `[0.3, 0.8]`. Плотность равна двойке в точках этого отрезка и нулю во всех остальных точках.